# How do I disable window move with alt + left mouse button in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

Title pretty much explains it all. I tried viewing other questions with the same topic, but none of the solutions work.

I tried CCSM, and I de-ticked "Move Window", nothing happened. I tried using gconf-editor to change /apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier, but still, it didn't work.

Is there any solution? I'm using Xubuntu, by the way.

Comment: What commands exactly do you not want?  Which ones are annoying you?

Comment: I don't care about other commands. I just want to stop <ALT> + click to stop moving/dragging windows.

Comment: So you want to be able to press <Alt> and move the mouse without effecting the windows?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you go to the Xfce menu and choose settings > settings manager > window manager tweaks > accessibility, you can select another key instead of alt  to move the windows or choose **none** at all. This should be just what you want.

You can also use [`xfconf-query`](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/xfconf-query) to set `easy_click` to none (or another key) on the command-line:

```
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/easy_click -s none
```

[image]

Comment: @Brandon  Please [accept](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1137/44179) this answer if it solved your problem :)